# HTML How to set range of values for input depending on answer in another input

Tags: javascript, html

on my web form I have a question that asks for the date of birth and the gender.

I want to make a check using Javascript that makes sure that if the user selected "male" he has to be over 18 and under 55 years old. But if they selected "female" they have to be over 20 and under 50 years old.

(Sample of my HTML)I have:

```html
<b>Gender: </b><br>
    <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="male" required>  Male
    <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="female" required>  Female
    <br><br>
    <b>Date of Birth: </b><br>
    <input type="date" name="dob" required >
    <br><br>
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Where is your JavaScript code? Did you try to implement anything by now?

Comment: Nothing, I don't know where to start! I'm trying to learn how to use javascript and HTML, but I don't know exactly how to write a code and link it in HTML. I can code in C++ and Python just fine though

Comment: have you taken any kind of JavaScript tutorial to learn the basics? It will show you all about where to place the code, linking it to events when the user makes a selection, etc. It sounds like you haven't studied any of that? Best to understand the fundamentals before attempting anything more specific. Walk before you try to run.

Comment: I did look at basic Javascript videos and resources such as w3schools. However, none of them really cover what I am trying to do.
I guess I'm trying to jump into the ocean and learn to swim!

Comment: I would imagine most of them cover setting up an event handler on an element, running some code when the event occurs, checking the value which is currently stored in a field, and displaying a message to the user. Maybe not all together, but certainly all those topics would be covered at some point. When you describe your requirement generically it's actually all basic stuff you would find in most tutorials, or can google other existing examples of. You mention you're an experienced programmer in other languages...so you have the skills to discover a new language and try something yourself.

Comment: Give it a go, if you get stuck, that would be a good time to ask a question on SO and post your code with an explanation of what goes wrong. Most of what goes on on this site is bug-fixing rather than giving out free examples of basic functionality, especially when the same kinds of examples are already available online many times over.

Comment: Hey, I posted what I ended up doing below, but it doesn't stop the browser from submiting the post though its out of bounds. any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there weren't any helpful answers, this is what I ended up doing myself:

```
function checkGender() {
var test = document.getElementById("male").checked;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = test;
if (test == true) {
    ageMin = 18;
    ageMax = 55;
} else {
    ageMin = 20;
    ageMax = 50;
}
//The following are only used to test that the values work
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = ageMin;
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = ageMax;

var dateString = document.getElementById("doB").value;
var today = new Date();
var birthDate = new Date(dateString);
var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
var m = today.getMonth()- birthDate.getMonth();
document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = dateString;
document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML = today;


if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
    age--;
}
document.getElementById("demo5").innerHTML = age;

if (age<ageMin || age>ageMax) {
     alert("Age is outside limits, please try again.");
     stop();
}   
}
```

HTML side of things:

```
<div class="form-row">
        <br>
    <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-1">Gender:</legend>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" id="male" type="radio" 
  name="Gender" value="male" required checked name="gender">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="male">
                    Male
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">        
                <input id="female" type="radio" name="Gender" value="female" required name="gender">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="female">
                    Female
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label for="doB">Date of Birth:</label><br>
            <input id="doB" type="date" name="dob" required>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -3):

### Modifying `HTMLElement` attributes

Basically, what you're looking for is, when you click on the radio button it triggers a function that then modifies the attribute `min` and changes the date

```
maleRadioButton.addEventListener('click', () => dateInput.setAttribute('min', new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() - 18)).toLocaleDateString())
```

FYI, I sincerely hope that there the reason for using different age ranges for different genders is not sexist.

Comment: Hi, absolutely not! I even considered adding an "other" option for gender so that I am more inclusive. I just chose those values to simplify the question, the form is just meant for me to test my abilities in using javascript, not for any real purposes.